How do I template these functions with variable number of arguments?
I've been trying to do this and can't seem to be able to do it. So I created a series of functions that does the job for me. The basic idea is that I have a sequence of integers and they are between 2 and 4 integers, and I pad them with a -1 if the sequence length is less than 4 because my integers are always positive:
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int, int> sequence_t;

int sequence_id(int a, int b) {
    sequence_t key = {a, b, -1, -1};
    if (!this->m_sequence_id.contains(key)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return this->m_sequence_id[key];
}

int sequence_id(int a, int b, int c) {
    sequence_t key = {a, b, c, -1};
    if (!this->m_sequence_id.contains(key)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return this->m_sequence_id[key];
}

int sequence_id(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    sequence_t key = {a, b, c, d};
    if (!this->m_sequence_id.contains(key)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return this->m_sequence_id[key];
}

But I'm sure there's a more effective way of doing this.
I tried a lot of different things and even grabbed my book on templates, but I couldn't get my code to pad the tuple correctly. It wouldn't compile (most of the times because the index to which I was calling std::get was a variable).
Is there a simple way of doing this?

You don't need a template. You want the last function to be int sequence_id(int a, int b, int c = -1, int d = -1).

You can use plain overloads. When possible that is much simpler than variadic templates. You only have to implement this one:
int sequence_id(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    sequence_t key = {a, b, c, d};
    if (!this->m_sequence_id.contains(key)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return this->m_sequence_id[key];
}

The others just call it:
int sequence_id(int a, int b, int c) { return sequence_id(a,b,c,-1); }
int sequence_id(int a, int b) { return sequence_id(a,b,-1,-1); }


What you are looking for is default argument values.
int sequence_id(int a, int b, int c = -1, int d = -1) {
    sequence_t key = {a, b, c, d};
    if (!this->m_sequence_id.contains(key)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return this->m_sequence_id[key];
}

And you can call
sequence_id(1, 0);
sequence_id(2, 1, 0);
sequence_id(3, 2, 1, 0);


Gosh! Thanks :) New to C++.

@E.S. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
